# Executing a ng-table sample code leads to $injector:modulerr error

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

For my Thesis want to build an application in Angularjs 1.5.6. I googled about AngularJS Tables and i found an [Example](http://ng-table.com/#/editing/demo-inline) I want to use as template for the application. I downloaded the source code, copied it into local files, changed the HTML code to fit into a typical HTML file and added the script tags like this.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ng-table demo</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.css">
    <script src="Controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 *HTML Code from Example comes here*

</body>

</html>
```

The javascript Code from the Website is inside a file called Controller.js which is referenced in a script-tag after the reference to angularjs.

My problem is that once i start the website the chrome developer tools shows me following error.

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

The error contains a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.2%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:25:147%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:24:211)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:24:454%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:39:287%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:39:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:43:164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.2%2Fangular.min.js:20:463)  but since i'm pretty new to angular and  i don't know how to fix the error. What i understand is that the error happens when referenced modules can't be loaded by Angular but all referenced scripts are downloaded fine and i referenced my javascript controller file in the html file.

I hope you can help me.

Greetings

Comment: check for ng-app value in js and script include

Comment: You are right. The ng-app and module declerations where different. I changed them all to "myApp" but the error still remails.